# ibus quit immediately when shut the terminal, ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, ibus

as the title name, i open terminal in ubuntu 22.04, write the CLI$ `ibus-daemon &`, it runs and the `switch language icon` appear on top-right corner. But when i shut the terminal, the `ibus` shut too and the `switch language icon` disappear. This is a bug or i do some thing wrong? I've just installed Ubuntu and make install for java-20 before the `ibus` thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the parent process (shell) dies, the child process (ibus-daemon) dies, too.

Comment: it's not clear much for me. I do the same routine before many times, it mean I open terminal, run 'ibus-daemon $' and shut the terminal, the "switch language icon" still there. I don't know much about concurrency or coroutine, but the principle should be "same result follow by same action". Am I right?